# Referencing a nested enum/type outside of the parent (struct/type) where the parent is generic

Tags: swift

I have a View Component (`MyViewWrapper`) that has a nested enum (`Value`):

```swift
struct MyViewWrapper<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var value: Value
    let content: Content
    
    public init(value: Binding<Value>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self._value = value
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content
    }
    
    enum Value {
        case percent(Double)
        case points(Double)
    }
}
```

Referencing the enum (`Value`) inside the component isn't an issue, but when I try to instantiate a `Value` outside of the struct:

```swift
struct SampleView: View {
    @State var value: MyViewWrapper.Value = .percent(0.5)
    
    var body: some View {
        MyViewWrapper(value: $value) {
            Color.red
        }
    }
}
```

I get a `Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred` error, as the parent struct/type is generic.

Sure, I could just extract the enum and call it something like `MyViewWrapperValue`. But I would really like to reference like so:

```swift
@State var value: MyViewWrapper.Value = .percent(0.5)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Nested types within generic types are a pitfall in the language. You always have to define a placeholder for the outer type.

---

If your code is simple enough that you actually know what `Content` is, you can use the horrible (but compiling) option of using it explicitly:

```swift
@State var value: MyViewWrapper<Color>.Value = .percent(0.5)
```

---

A more scalable approach is to keep it as a nested type that refers to something concrete. E.g.

```swift
struct MyViewWrapper<Content: View>: View {
  typealias Value = MyViewWrapper<Never>._Value
```

```swift
extension MyViewWrapper where Content == Never {
  enum _Value {
    case percent(Double)
    case points(Double)
  }
}
```

Then, you can use `Value` or `_Value` interchangeably elsewhere.

```swift
struct SampleView: View {
  @State var value: MyViewWrapper<Never>.Value = .percent(0.5)
```

Whether that's better than a non-nested namespace-cluttering `MyViewWrapperValue` is debatable.

Comment: Well, this is absolutely disgusting . Appreciate the context and direct answer to the question, though! Guess I'm going with `MyViewWrapperValue`!